# Make predictions from a saved trained classifier in Scikit Learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I wrote a classifier for Tweets in Python which then I saved it in `.pkl` format on disk, so I can run it again and again without the need to train it each time. This is the code:

```
import pandas
import re
from sklearn.feature_extraction import FeatureHasher

from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2

from sklearn import cross_validation

from sklearn.externals import joblib


#read the dataset of tweets

header_row=['sentiment','tweetid','date','query', 'user', 'text']
train = pandas.read_csv("training.data.csv",names=header_row)

#keep only the right columns

train = train[["sentiment","text"]]

#remove puctuation, special characters, numbers and lower case the text

def remove_spch(text):

    return re.sub("[^a-z]", ' ', text.lower())

train['text'] = train['text'].apply(remove_spch)


#Feature Hashing

def tokens(doc):
    """Extract tokens from doc.

    This uses a simple regex to break strings into tokens.
    """
    return (tok.lower() for tok in re.findall(r"\w+", doc))

n_features = 2**18
hasher = FeatureHasher(n_features=n_features, input_type="string", non_negative=True)
X = hasher.transform(tokens(d) for d in train['text'])

y = train['sentiment']

X_new = SelectKBest(chi2, k=20000).fit_transform(X, y)

a_train, a_test, b_train, b_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X_new, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier 

classifier=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)                  
classifier.fit(a_train.toarray(), b_train)                            
prediction = classifier.predict(a_test.toarray()) 

#Export the trained model to load it in another project

joblib.dump(classifier, 'my_model.pkl', compress=9)
```

Let's say that I have another Python file and I want to classify a Tweet. How can I proceed to do the classification?

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
model_clone = joblib.load('my_model.pkl')

mytweet = 'Uh wow:@medium is doing a crowdsourced data-driven investigation tracking down a disappeared refugee boat'
```

Up to the `hasher.transform` I can replicate the same procedure to add it to the prediction model, but then I have the problem that I cannot calculate the best 20k features. To use the SelectKBest, you need to add both features and label. Since, I want to predict the label, I cannot use the SelectKBest. So, how can I pass this issue to continue on the prediction?

Comment: sorry have you actually tried loading the tweet into an array and passing this to your `model_clone` and called `predict`?

Comment: Shouldn't I pass from the same preparation the text and then try to predict? If I just pass the text in a list and then to classifier, I have this error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: Uh wow:@medium is doing a crowdsourced data-driven investigation tracking down a disappeared refugee boat`

Comment: Correct you need to perform the same feature extraction as you did when you trained and pass this as the data

Comment: @EdChum And here is my problem. In the previous feature extraction, I had a big dataset to use on the training. It was a labeled one and I use both text and label to find the features. How I am supposed to do it again when I have only one tweet or a list with 10 tweets but without a label, since I am trying to predict it? I would be grateful if you could provide specific details as an answer :)

Comment: What do you mean without labels? I don't understand why it's not possible to extract the features again? You need to code this so that it extracts the same features you used for training

Comment: `X` is the features, `y` is the label. The sentiment from the training data. The feature selection needs a label column and I don't have it for the new texts that I want to do the prediction. If there is any other way, I am not aware of it :(

Comment: Sorry the point is you use your model to *predict* what the label is, whether it's correct or not is something *you* need to decide. The point being is that you build a model by training it on data which presumably is representative enough for it to cope with unseen data

Answer (score 5):

I support the comment of @EdChum that

> you build a model by training it on data which presumably is representative enough for it to cope with unseen data

Practically this means that you need to apply both `FeatureHasher` and `SelectKBest` to your new data with `predict` *only*. (It is *wrong* to train FeatureHasher anew on the new data, because in general it will produce different features).

To do this either

- pickle `FeatureHasher` and `SelectKBest` separately

or (better)

- make a `Pipeline` of FeatureHasher, SelectKBest, and `RandomForestClassifier` and pickle the whole pipeline. Then you can load this pipeline and use `predict` on a new data.

Comment: Seems valid, but unfortunately, I haven't created a `Pipeline` before. Can you please provide also the procedure on my example?

Comment: Scikit learn has a good example on their [site](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html)

Comment: Is there a way to pass the classifier labels in with the pipeline?